# Routing issue in Laravel

Tags: php, apache, laravel, routes, xampp

I am trying to implement a login system in Laravel (4.2), but some of my routes throw a 404 error. For example, my routes for authenticating a user and logging them in work just fine. Then when I hit logout, Laravel routes me back to localhost/logout while it should be localhost/laravel/public/logout. When I enter that URL manually it logs out OK and redirects back to the login page like it's supposed to. Not quite sure what's wrong since my httpd.conf has AllowOverride All and mod_rewrite is being loaded. I am using the latest version of XAMPP on Ubuntu if that makes a difference.

In UsersController.php:

```
public function logout()
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        Auth::logout();
    }
    return Redirect::route('login');    
}
```

routes.php:

```
Route::get('/logout', array('as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'UsersController@logout'));
```

in my view it's like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        @if (Auth::check())
        <li><a href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
        <li><a href="/profile">{{ Auth::user()->username }}</a></li>
        @else
        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/register">Sign Up</a></li>
        @endif
     </ul>
```

**EDIT** My login route:

```
Route::get('login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'UsersController@login'));
```

which simply loads the login view:

```
public function login()
{
    return View::make('users.login');
}
```

**EDIT 2** httpd.conf

```
 Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
 Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/laravel/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**EDIT 3** Problem was fixed by Razor's suggestion in the comments. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: is your `Redirect::route('login')` a named route. you didn't show that part of your code

Comment: @Kombian updated the question to include the login route.

Comment: Try explicitly setting the document root by adding `DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/laravel/public` above your directory definition.

Comment: I tried it and when trying to restart apache, XAMPP couldn't close the apache instance (apachectl returned 1 error) so I had to undo the changes to httpd.conf to make it reboot normally. The suggestion didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, that should have had quotation marks around it: `DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/laravel/public"`. Also make sure there are no spelling errors in the path name.

Comment: how about `{{link_to_route('logout', 'Log Out');}}` ?

Comment: @lowerends It works only if I don't set anything after "htdocs", otherwise it throws an HTTP exception. Also you were right, it was misspelled - I had to take out apache2 from path name because it goes lampp/htdocs. Issue persists.

Comment: @Razor this worked, thank you. Should I write all my links in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `href="logout"` instead of `href="/logout"`, it should work. But I recommend to use [Url helpers](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls):

```
{{link_to_route('logout', 'Log Out');}}
{{link_to('/login', 'Login');}}
<li><a href="{{URL::to('/register')}}">Sign Up</a></li>
```

Comment: In Laravel, what do forward slashes signify when defining routes? I tested with and without them. App worked without slashes just fine so I decided to ditch them.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
Route::get('/logout', array('as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'UsersController@logout'));
```

to this:

```
Route::get('logout', array('as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'UsersController@logout'));
```

without the leading `/`.

Comment: Same problem unfortunately.

Comment: Is your document root set correctly to `localhost/laravel/public`?